# Inferir tipo de una propiedad para usar en llamada a método genérico

Tags: c#, genericos

tengo la siguiente problemática. Tengo un método genérico el cual requiere que especifiquemos un tipo. El caso es que el tipo debo obtenerlo de la propiedad de una clase, y dicha propiedad la tenemos como valor cadena:

```
private static int DoUpdate<T, R, RKey>(ISource<T> sourceService, IDestination<R, RKey> destinationService, IParser<T, R> parser, string linkedProperty)
    where T : TavoraDataSource.BaseEntity
    where R : BaseEntity<RKey>
{
        // Línea donde da el error
        T itemV1 = sourceService.GetByLinkedPropertyId<typeof(T).GetProperty(linkedProperty).GetType()>(linkedProperty, item.Id);
```

Yo veía claro que con GetType() obtendría el tipo requerido pero me encuentro que el compilador me tira un error.

Gracias

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Veo que el premio a 'la mejor explicación de un problema' no me lo llevo este año. Intento explicarme mejor.

Os pongo el contexto: se está desarrollando software para sustituir otro de hace 20 años e igualmente se está migrando la base de datos a otra con una estructura mejorada. Por motivos que no vienen al caso las dos bases de datos van a estar un tiempo conviviendo siendo la original la única que recibirá datos mientras la nueva va siendo actualizado por un programa de consola que va actualizando los datos que vayan siendo modificados en la original.

El problema es que la base de datos original es bastante caótica y cada tabla tiene una clave primaria con un nombre distinto. Para poder actualizar los registros en la base de datos nueva tengo que obtener el mismo registro en la base de datos original pero para ello debo pasar el tipo que tiene la clave de la tabla original para poder convertir el valor ya que si no me tira error de que los tipos no coinciden.

Simplifico el código que inicialmente puse para quitar todo aquello que no es importante para esta cuestión:

```
// 'T' es una entidad de la base de datos original
// 'R' es una entidad de la base de datos nueva
// 'item' es un registro de la base de datos nueva
// 'linkedProperty' es una propiedad de 'T' que es la clave primaria, cada entidad de la base de datos original tiene un nombre y tipo distinto (este es el verdadero problema y origen de toda la complicación)

        private static int DoUpdate<T, R>(R item, string linkedProperty)
        {
                // Partiendo del ID del elemento R (long) necesito encontrar el mismo registro en la base de datos original que puede ser uint, int o long

// ERROR: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'type' and 'type'
                T itemV1 = sourceService.GetByLinkedPropertyId<typeof(T).GetProperty(linkedProperty).GetType()>(linkedProperty, item.Id);
```

**GetByLinkedPropertyId**

```
public TEntity GetByLinkedPropertyId<TKey>(string linkedProperty, TKey id) 
{
// Construyo la expresión lambda ya que no es posible usar reflexión para generar el SQL 
    var whereClause = GetExpression<TKey>(linkedProperty, id);

    return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(whereClause).FirstOrDefault();
}

private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetExpression<TKey>(string propertyName, TKey id)
{
    // Creamos la parte x => de la expresion
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");

    // Creamos la parte de la expresion que identifica la propiedad de X
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    // Creamos la parte ID
// NECESITO CONVERTIR id DE LA ENTIDAD DE LA BD NUEVA AL TIPO QUE TIENE EN LA ORIGINAL
    var equalsTo = Expression.Constant((TKey)id);

    // Creamos la igualdad
    var equality = Expression.Equal(property, equalsTo);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(equality, new[] { parameter });
}
```

No sé si he aclarado el problema o lo he enredado más.

Gracias por vuestro interés

Comment: No se entiende. "... Tengo un método genérico ..", supongo te refieres a GetByLinkedPropertyId o no? . "y dicha propiedad la tenemos como valor cadena" eso tampoco lo entendí

Comment: Que error te da? asi podemos ver algo, porque al no tener todas esas definiciones no podemos meterlo en un compilador...

Comment: Igual algo no me cuadra... Algo de tipo T, que tiene una propiedad que estas buscando, devuelve algo de tipo T?

Comment: @gbianchi Claro, la lógica diría que debería ser algo así T itemV1 = sourceService.GetByLinkedPropertyId<T>(linkedProperty, item.Id)

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el código donde llamas a la función y el código de `TavoraDataSource.BaseEntity` parámetro? Podría ayudarnos a entenderte.

Comment: Acabo de subir una modificación intentando ser más preciso. Gracias por el interés

Comment: El error es que lo esta tomando como si fuera el operador menor??? hay algun otro error en el codigo?

Comment: Luego de leer nuevamente todo el caso, sigo sin entender para qué enredarte con los árboles de expresiones. ¿Has considerado en agregar nuevas filas a todas las tablas a modo de PKs? Me refiero a que en casos extremos como el tuyo, lo más práctico sería "estandarizar una nueva PK" tipo "IdNewToMigrate", autonumérico con incremento de 1 en 1 y utilizar dicho campo para sincronizar lo que tengas que sincronizar. De los casos más raros que he escuchado fue de una base de datos con 5-6 "PKs", cortesía de 5-6 migraciones "fuertes" que hicieron a un mal diseño de base de datos. Buena suerte :D

Comment: Pues no había considerado esa opción. Puede que sea lo más sencillo. A veces nos enredamos sin necesidad alguna. Gracias por la idea

Answer (score 1):

Aunque el usuario @fredyfx me dio una idea válida seguí dándole vueltas a como realizarlo de la forma que tenía inicialmente en la cabeza.

Finalmente encontré esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/1587968 que resolvió el problema.

La definición del tipo en la llamada al método genérico que estaba intentando realizar a través del código

```
T itemV1 = sourceService.GetByLinkedPropertyId<typeof(T).GetProperty(linkedProperty).GetType()>(linkedProperty, item.Id);
```

debe ser sustituida por

```
        MethodInfo method = typeof(ISource<T>).GetMethod(nameof(sourceService.GetByLinkedPropertyId));
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T).GetProperty(linkedProperty).PropertyType);

        T itemV1 = generic.Invoke(sourceService, new object[] { linkedProperty, Convert.ChangeType(item.Id, typeof(T).GetProperty(linkedProperty).PropertyType) }) as T;
```

Donde usamos correctamente la reflexión para construir la llamada al método.

Espero que sirva a alguien que se encuentre con el mismo problema